# passing two tableadaptercolletions to view

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view, zend-framework3

I'm still trying to get as "hierarchical" view the recordssets of a second tableadapter collection.

In my controlleraction I passed a second argument to the view:

```
return new ViewModel([
            'projects' => $this->projectTable->fetchAll(),
            'dcls' => $this->table->fetchAll()
            ]);
```

In my view I thought I could grab the second collection as I did with the first:

```
foreach ($projects as $project) : 
?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $project['Projectname']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['ProjectShortcut']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['ProjectCiNumber']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['Unitname']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['UnitShortcut']?></td>
    <td><?= $project['UnitCiNumber']?></td>
    <td>
            <a href="<?= $this->url('import', ['action' => 'edit', 'id' => $import->DCLID]) ?>">Edit</a>
            <a href="<?= $this->url('import', ['action' => 'delete', 'id' => $import->DCLID]) ?>">Delete</a>
        </td>

        <?php foreach ($dcls->getImportunit($project['UnitID']) as $dcl) : ?>
            <td><?= $dcl['Importdate']?></td>
        <?php  endforeach; ?>

  <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

But that doesn't work, I have some understanding issues.

if I try `$dcls->getImportunit($project['UnitID']) as $dcl`

then I get an error

> Call to undefined method Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::getImportunit()

The method is placed in my model and it is public.

If I call just to try: `<?php foreach ($dcls as $dcl) :

            <td><?= $dcl['Importdate']?></td>
        <?php  endforeach; ?>`
I get an error

> Cannot use object of type Import\Model\Import as array

Interesting I used the same syntax like for projects?

If I use as an object attribut :

```
<?php foreach ($dcls as $dcl) :         
        <td><?= $dcl->Importdate?></td>
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
```

I get an error

> This result is a forward only result set, calling rewind() after moving forward is not supported

This one makes sense for, I just tried different possibilies to get a clue if my dcl Records are usable in my view.

So I have two questions. why can't I grad the columns as an error like I have done with projects.
And why can't I use my method? It seems like the collection dcls is not properly passed.

So besides the little understanding issues my target shall be to scroll through the second collection (dcl) while using a parameter of the first collection (project)

EDIT1: following the suggestions from jobaer

Here first my new code:

Controller/indexAction

```
$dcls = $this->table->fetchAll();

        // make an array for dcl
        $secondCollection  = array($dcls);

        foreach ($dcls as $dcl) {

            // if this is a resultset pass into view as you need
            $importUnits = $dcl->getImportunit($project['UnitID']);
            $secondCollection['importdate'] = $dcl->importdate;
            $secondCollection['DCL_Path'] = $dcl->DCL_Path;
        }

        // pass $secondCollection via model
        return new ViewModel([
                'projects' => $this->projectTable->fetchAll(),
                'dcls' => $secondCollection,
        ]);
```

Question: How could this work as how I understand the view gets every recordset of projects and if I here try to get the secondCollection related to UnitID, how can it work in the view? For my understanding the passing to the view is executed only once if I call the route, isn't it? or am I wrong in this case?

This one `$importUnits = $dcl->getImportunit($project['UnitID']);` in this snipped might have no effect?

Answer (score 0):

> Call to undefined method Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet::getImportunit()

This is you are getting because you are not calling that method in a way that should not be.

> Cannot use object of type Import\Model\Import as array

You cant call an object as array unless it is implicitly defined to be called as an array inside that class you are calling on.

> This result is a forward only result set, calling `rewind()` after moving forward is not supported

You are getting this because, generally you cant loop over over again for the result set you are returning if you do not rewind the internal pointer to the beginning, this result set uses SPL Iterator.

So to meet this issue you can use `buffer()` method with the result set before returning it.

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
    $resultSet->buffer(); // This is the point here

    return $resultSet ;
}
```

Buffering is a feature of `Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet`, which you can use to wrap a driver result.

**Edit:**

Whatever is related to model, you must do that in the model. As you are coming across loop problem with the result sets, you do the trick with the help of the model. What this means is to create an array from the result set in your controller method and then pass it to the view.

For example, you are doing so as the following in the view to fulfill your needs.

```
foreach ($projects as $project) : 

    // here you are looping for project

    foreach ($dcls as $dcl) :

        // Here you want to loop for dcl

    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

But for the above described reason you cant use loop inside another loop.

```
'projects' => $this->projectTable->fetchAll(),
'dcls' => $this->table->fetchAll()
```

As you know `$projects` and `$dcls` return resultsets. That's why I told you to make arrays from those resultsets in the controller methods.

You already know what to display from `$projects` and `$dcls`. So make arrays from resultsets as below

```
$secondCollection  = array();
foreach ($dcls as $dcl) {
    $secondCollection['importdate'] = $dcl->importdate;
    $secondCollection['DCL_Path'] = $dcl->DCL_Path;
}
```

Do the same technic for others if you need.

Now if you need any resultset by specific ID or NAME then you should process the thing in your controller method using model's method help. For example

```
$projects = $this->projectTable->getProjectByUnitId($unitId);
```

Now you know `$projects` is also a resultset, so you can make it an array as above.

Then pass all of the arrays made from different resultsets in the view...

```
return new ViewModel([
    'array_name1' => $array_name1,
    'array_name_2' => $array_name_2,
]);
```

Hope this would help you!

Comment: ok, now I get always the first recordset. I still want to use my method, do you have a clue why I can't use it? Because with the $dcl I have a table object, right?

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope that would help you! Thanks

Comment: Well, I am sorry that wont help you as you expected. I tried to tell you that you're passing `'projects'` and  `'dcls'` as variable into the view. How are you doing this? To do that you are taking help of model here. So if you need result from project table based on unit ID, you generally make a method like `getProjectByUnitId($unitId)`. I see you were trying to fetch something thus. Do things like that to fulfill you needs in your controller. Then make arrays of them. So that you can use them in the view using loop. They do not emit error like it did before.

Comment: No that is not the right way, I want to show dcls based on UnidID, I have no problem with datamodelling.